# Comparing Layer, Applozic, Quickblox & SendBird for quick WhatsApp like messaging in an Android App

Tags: android, layer, quickblox, sendbird, applozic

We at Wishbook have a B2B mobile application (Android & iPhone), wherein we are looking to implement Text & photo communication - between users 1-to-1, or from a user to his group of buyers. We are keen on something that can get us upto speed ASAP, offers good support, is mature library / server, and is also battery friendly.

We are now comparing between Layer, Applozic, QuickBlox & SendBird. Anyone used them? What protocols (XMPP / MQTT / custom / other) are used by them? Experience using it - interms of stable code base, etc? Also - we prefer open-source & more pocket friendly product as well.

Thanks,
Arvind

Comment: I've spent much of the last few weeks using Sendbird with Javascript and iOS so while I can't talk about Android, if it's like iOS in design, I'd recommend something else. The core service does many of the things you want for messaging, but both SDKs were extremely difficult to use in a way that fit our application.

Answer (score 13):

I have recently just tested two of the solutions you have cited.

QuickBlox :

- protocol xmpp
- open source
- documentated less clearly than applozic
- easy set up

Applozic :

- protocol mqtt
- open source easy set up, if a bit laborious
- well documented, and very easy API to use.
- Very customizable.

Both programs:

- have video call/audio call/groups
- have code bases that are constantly being updated, and from their Github pages new version have been released in the past few months

I preferred Applozic as the user interface was nicer and easier to use, and the features and pricing clearer. I also preferred the API and the setup code was easier.

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar question. 
The following charts mentioned in the articles helped me finalise the chat api to be used.
[Feature Comparison](https://www.applozic.com/blog/applozic-vs-sendbird-vs-layer-vs-quickblox-alternatives/) and
[Pricing](https://www.applozic.com/blog/applozic-vs-sendbird-vs-layer-vs-quickblox-discover-your-best-chat-sdk/)

Applozic has cross app communication and broadcast messaging as well. Support is very quick with Applozic.